# Why are String comparisons (CompareTo) faster in Java than in C#?

Tags: c#, java, performance

## EDIT3:

Using

```
StringComparer comparer1 = StringComparer.Ordinal;
```

instead of

```
IComparable v
IComparable w
comparer1.Compare(v, w)
```

Solved the runtime issue.

---

I've done some Benchmarks on sorting algorithms (e.g. Quicksort, Mergesort) in Java and C#.

I used Java 7 and the .NET Framework 4.5 for implementing and executing my algorithms. It showed that all Algorithms could achieve better runtimes using Java.

Some example runtimes for Quicksort:

**C#**

1. n=1000000 4433 ms
2. n=2000000 10047 ms

**Java**

1. n=1000000 1311 ms
2. n=2000000 3164 ms

Then I've done measures using profiling tools: C# used 75% of the runtime for String comparisons (i.e. CompareTo), whereas Java only used 2% of the runtime for comparisons.

Why are String comparisons so expensive in C# and not in Java?

EDIT:
I've also tested the C# sort function Arrays.sort(INPUT) it could achieve about 3000 ms for n=1000000, so i don't think the code is the problem. But anyway:

Here's the code for Quicksort:

```
public class Quicksort {

public static void sort(IComparable[] a) {
    sort(a, 0, a.Length - 1);
}

private static void sort(IComparable[] a, int lo, int hi) { 
    if (hi <= lo) return;
    int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
    sort(a, lo, j-1);
    sort(a, j+1, hi);
}

private static int partition(IComparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    int i = lo;
    int j = hi + 1;
    IComparable v = a[lo];
    while (true) { 

        while (less(a[++i], v))
            if (i == hi) break;

        while (less(v, a[--j]))
            if (j == lo) break; 


        if (i >= j) break;

        exch(a, i, j);
    }

    exch(a, lo, j);

    return j;
}


public static IComparable select(IComparable[] a, int k) {
    if (k < 0 || k >= a.Length) {
        throw new Exception("Selected element out of bounds");
    }
    Rnd.Shuffle(a);
    int lo = 0, hi = a.Length - 1;
    while (hi > lo) {
        int i = partition(a, lo, hi);
        if      (i > k) hi = i - 1;
        else if (i < k) lo = i + 1;
        else return a[i];
    }
    return a[lo];
}


private static bool less(IComparable v, IComparable w) {
    return (v.CompareTo(w) < 0);
}
    
private static void exch(Object[] a, int i, int j) {
    Object swap = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = swap;
}

}
```

Quicksort is measured then as follows:

```
Stopwatch.Restart();
Quicksort.sort(stringArray);
Stopwatch.Stop();
```

EDIT2: Somebody wanted to see the Java version. It's exactly the same i just use Comparable instead of IComparable and Array.length instead of Array.Length

Comment: Please show the code you're using. There are a number of things which could be affecting this.

Comment: I have a *suspicion* about what's going on here - but I'm waiting to see the code.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I don't think he's trying to make any claims here.  I assume he's doing the right thing, trying to determine what the cause might be, before drawing conclusions.  But indeed we need to see the test methodology to help them with that.

Comment: please post the java version too.

Comment: string interning in Java while not in C#?

Comment: If that is all of the code, then it is most likely that your poor benchmarking methodology is distorting the numbers you are getting.  IMO, they are not reliable.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> so i don't think the code is the problem

I beg to differ. You're not comparing the same things in both cases. Admittedly it doesn't help that you *also* haven't shown us how you generate the strings etc, but Java and .NET perform different default string comparisons.

From Java's [`String.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29):

> Compares two strings lexicographically.

And from .NET's [`String.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/35f0x18w.aspx):

> This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) comparison using the current culture.

It's no surprise that this is slower than doing a purely lexicographic comparison.

It's easy to see this when just comparing .NET with itself...

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] source = GenerateRandomStrings();
        string[] workingSpace = new string[source.Length];

        CopyAndSort(source, workingSpace);
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            CopyAndSort(source, workingSpace);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: {0}ms", 
                          (long) sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    static string[] GenerateRandomStrings()
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        string[] ret = new string[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < ret.Length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = GenerateRandomString(rng);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    static string GenerateRandomString(Random rng)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = (char) rng.Next('A', 'z' + 1);
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }

    static void CopyAndSort(string[] original, string[] workingSpace)
    {
        Array.Copy(original, 0, workingSpace, 0, original.Length);
        Array.Sort(workingSpace);
        // Array.Sort(workingSpace, StringComparer.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

Try it yourself, varying the `CopyAndSort` method based on whether you specify an ordinal string comparer or not. It's *much* faster with the ordinal comparer, at least on my box.

Comment: Is there a reason you call the `CopyAndSort` once before the measurement? Or is it just to make sure that every run starts with the same `workingSpace` state (i.e. sorted)?

Comment: @poke: Nope, it's to make sure it's all been JIT-compiled before we start measuring.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that in C# the .Net platform might do by default some extended checks like proper skipping of annotation or whitespace unicode characters and Java might don't do them by default. I think that Java's runtime performs simplier byte-2-byte comparison, but I may be very wrong here, as it's quite a long time since I've touched the details of working with encodings in Java, so that's pure guessing.

Another thing: there may be some differences in default comparison behaviour between those two platforms. If you just use the defaults, without any precise settings, I'd guess that you simply implicitely requested different behaviors.

At least in .Net there are many string comparison options. It might have happened that you simply took similar-looking function that actually does a different comparison that the Java's. Have you tried with detailed overload like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190416.aspx ? Note that this is a `static` method to be used bit differently:

```
var result1 = "mom".CompareTo("dad");
var result2 = string.Compare("mom", "dad", ...);
```

Please investigate the ComparisonOptions and/or CultureInfo settings, and adjust them so that the overall behaviour matches Java's behaviour as closely as possible. Also, you may have to pick a different overload at Java side too, if there are more of them.

Also, another difference may be in somewhat tricky fact, that the CompareTo method that you are testing is implementation of `IComparable<T>` interface that is meant to cross-compare various objects that implement this interface, and the static `Compare` method is designed to compare only strings. They simply may be optimized for different things. If there will be any performance difference between them, I'd bet the static `Compare` is faster for string-vs-string comparisons.

Comment: Well I also tested the C# sorting methods Arrays.Sort(input) and Collection.Sort() which leaded to 3000 ms runtimes for n=1000000 so Java still was 300% faster.

Comment: Default parameterless Arrays.Sort and Collection.Sort always use the most generic IComparable interface, because it does not have any other options. Those functions are designed to be 'easy and handy', not to be 'fastest' or 'lightest'. They even have to check if the LHS and RHS have the same type, which hits the performance even more. To finely tailor the performance, you may need to use sorting algos that **at least** take a `comparer` or `comparison delegate`, where you will be able to specify the exact comparison behaviours. But, let me say that again: all that I wrote is just guessing.

Comment: @user2025998: Try the same test specifying `StringComparer.Ordinal` as the comparison to use. Basically, Java uses ordinal comparison by default and .NET doesn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow you were right. I used StringComparer instead and achieved a runtime of 1545 ms for n=1000000.

Comment: @user2025998: Well, the important thing is *which* StringComparer you use. StringComparer.Ordinal makes it work the same way as Java, basically.